# redirect url that matches directory otherwise

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I use redirections quite a lot but I'm not able to achieve my goal despite searching.

What I like to achieve:

- a request to `/aaaa` redirected to `/articles/aaaa.php` 
  but only show `/aaaa` in browser (this already works for years)
- a request to `/bbbb` which is a directory, no file exist with this name, has to be redirected to `/products/bbbb/index.php` (but only show `/bbbb` in browser)*

This is what I use now:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /articles/$1.php [NC,L]
```

*as alternative if it is too complex this is ok: a request to /bbbb (which is a directory no file exist with this name) redirect to /products/bbbb (and in the directory /products/bbbb I'll pick it up there with a local .htaccess and redirect it to index.php) still in the browser /bbbb should be shown.

Comment: "a request to `/bbbb` which is a directory" - Although I assume `/bbbb` isn't actually a directory on the filesystem, but should be _internally rewritten_ to a directory of the same name in the `/products` directory if it exists?

Comment: indeed, bbbb is a directory in the fs so there is a directory /products/bbbb

Answer (score 0):

When rewriting to the file in the `/articles` directory you can check that it exists first (as a file). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/articles/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /articles/$1.php [L]
```

I've also removed the `NC` flag, unless you explicitly need this?

Likewise to *internally rewrite* to the directory:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/products/$1/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /products/$1/index.php [L]
```

This actually checks that the `index.php` *file* exists, rather than the parent directory, since you are ultimately rewriting to a file, not a directory.